# Android: Loading lots of data from an XML handler in a ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, listadapter

I'm parsing a large XML document and showing its contents in a ListView. Initially I was parsing the entire thing and then showing it all at once, but this takes pretty long to load (~30 seconds on some devices).

Now, as soon as my SAX handler gets an object I add it to an array and notify my list adapter that the data changed. This brings up a new problem because I'm rapidly refreshing the ListView the user is unable to scroll or select an item.

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind.

1. Make sure you are loading the data in a background thread
2. Don't overwhelm the UI loading one object at a time. Do them in batches of 10 or whatever number makes sense for you app.

Comment: Everything is in a background thread, but I am loading each UI object one at a time. I'll try batching it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a progressdialog in a class that extends `AsyncTask`.

> class MyAsyncLoad extends AsyncTask{

```
        ProgressDialog myprogsdial;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            myprogsdial = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, null, "Loading...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //here you are doing parsing stuff and load data into your datastructure, or whatever you use to store data from XML
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
            myprogsdial.dismiss();

            //here you update the cursor,something like
            adapter = new CursorAdapter(context, cursor...)
            setListAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```